# Missions are gone?

Tags: android, tiny-tower

Since the latest in-game update, the Android version of **Tiny Tower** now has "Saving VIPs" and the ability to select a specific store when building (for a lot of bux, too).

But all my Missions are gone. Both the available and completed missions show 0.

I didn't find anything at Mobage Support. I did find a lot of comments on Google Play Store reviews.

What's going on?

Oh, and incidentally, I have already:

- Force Stopped the app
- Cleared the app data
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled the app

None of which had any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today's update restored the Missions.